# how to check for valid integer quantity befor submit in shopping cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, validation, form-submit

Shopping cart quantity entry form is defined using code below. 
Quantity must be empty initially.

Form is submitted via ajax using jquery post().

How to check that quantity is filled with integer greater than 0 before submit?

I tried code below but alert box returns [htmlinputelement] and thus check fails.

```
    <form class='browse-addtocart-form' action="<%= Url.Action("AddToCartPost", "Store")%>" method="post">
       <input class='amount ui-corner-all' name="quantity" type="number" value=""
     size="3" min="0" step="1" /></span>
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
       </form>
  <script>    
    $(function() {
$(".browse-addtocart-form").submit(function(event){
    var $form = $(this);
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    alert($form[0].quantity);
    if ($form[0].quantity==="" || $form[0].quantity==="0") {
      alert('Please fill quantity with non zero integer');
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
      }
    $.post('<%= Url.Action("AddToCart", "Store")%>',
      serializedData, function(response) {
          $("#cart-status").text(response.Total);
          showMessage(response.Message);
          showFadeOutMessage(response.Message);
        }));
   event.preventDefault();
  });
  });
      </script>
```

jquery, jquery UI, ASP.NET MVC2 are used.

Comment: what do you mean by `thus check fails`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest might be to call parseInt and check that it does not return NaN.

```
var q = parseInt($form[0].quantity, 10);
if(isNaN(q) || q === 0){
  alert('Please fill quantity with non zero integer');
}
```

Edited to add base=10 to parseInt, and use isNaN(). Without adding an explicit base of 10, parseInt will mistake a string starting with a zero as an octal number, and the same for hex.

Comment: Thank you. I added `return false` to if statement. In this case alert box appears only on first click. Subsequent clicks to button are ignored, submit event does not fire on button click. How to fix this ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see anything obvious that would cause the event to only work the first time. One trick that might help debug this, if you're using something like Firebug or Chrome's built-in debugger, is to evaluate $(".browse-addtocart-form").data('events') and check that the submit handler is still properly bound. Also check the debugger log for any errors, or place a breakpoint in the handler to ensure that it really doesn't fire.

Comment: `$(".browse-addtocart-form").data('events')` returs undefined in FireBUg command prompt. It does not exist in firebug

Comment: My mistake, and it took me months to realise it. $().data('events') is deprecated from jquery 1.8 onwards. Instead you now have to use $._data($('.browse-addtocart-form')[0], 'events').

Answer (score 1):

A small note on your `event.preventDefault();`. You can do return false;` and that will stop sending your post too, you don't even need the event parameter for that.

As you already have `var serializedData = $form.serialize();`, I recommend you to extract the "quantity" out of there with `serializedData.quantity`.

Comment: I used code from  http: //stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example Why `return false` is not used in this hight score sample then?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function() {
    $(".browse-addtocart-form").submit(function(event) {
        var $form = $(this);
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();
        if (this.quantity.value === "" || this.quantity.value === "0") {
            alert('Please fill quantity with non zero integer');
            return false;
        }
        $.post('<%= Url.Action("AddToCart", "Store")%>',
                serializedData, function(response) {
                    $("#cart-status").text(response.Total);
                    showMessage(response.Message);
                    showFadeOutMessage(response.Message);
                });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Alert box appears only on first click. Subsequent clicks to button are ignored, submit method in not called on subsequent clicks. Only enter can used to submit. How to fix this ?